# 500 (Internal Server Error) Hosting Web in Google Cloud - Compute Engine VM + Firestore + PHP + Apache2

Tags: php, apache, google-cloud-firestore, google-compute-engine

The implementation of Web on Google Compute Engine VM (free trial) to connect to a firestore database has the following files:

**index.html:**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="result"></div>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function create () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'firestoreData.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { funct: "getData", name:"testArgument"},
            success: function(response) { 
                    console.log(response.result);              
            },
            error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
                console.log("error:" + exception);
            }
        
        });
      }
    </script>
    <button type="button" onclick="create()">Click Me</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

**firestoreData.php:**

```
<?php
namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\Firestore;
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
function getData($name)
{
  // Create the Cloud Firestore client
  $db = new FirestoreClient([
    'projectId' => 'project-id',
    'credentials' => 'project-XXX.json'
  ]);
  return json_encode(array('result'=>'successfuly registered'));
}
if ($_POST['funct']=="getData") { 
  echo getData($_POST['name']);
}
```

I got the error in the Chrome Explorer " 500 (Internal Server Error)". Please see
the image: [image: Capture Chrome]

If I remove the line in firestoreData.php there is no problem.

```
$db = new FirestoreClient([
        'projectId' => 'project-id',
        'credentials' => 'project-XXX.json'
      ]);
```

and if I check the firestoreData.php file in the VM console with the command:

```
php firestoreData.php
```

there is no problem. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Hi. When you remove which line that there's no problem? (There's more than one line that was removed in the 3rd snippet)

Comment: When I remove this lines:
  $db = new FirestoreClient([
    'projectId' => 'project-id',
    'credentials' => 'project-XXX.json'
  ]);

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the error adding extension=grpc.so in /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini. It should be also included in /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini.